# Trying to multiply a matrix with its transpose but not getting any result

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, transpose, matrix-multiplication

This code is for multiplication of a matrix with its transpose:

```
import numpy as np

def multiply_At_A(A):
    dim1 = A.shape[0]
    dim2 = A.shape[1]
    matrix = np.zeros([dim2,dim2])
    
    for i in range(dim2):
        for j in range(dim2):
            for k in range(dim1):
                matrix[i,j]==A[i,k]*A[k,j]
        return matrix
    A=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
    print(matrix)
```

I was supposed to get a result but i am not getting any result

Comment: Use Majid's answer for how to do this, but the problem with your code is that you never actually call your function. You need to move the `A=...` line at the bottom to outside the function then call the function with `matrix = multiply_At_A(A)`.

Comment: `matrix[i,j]==A[i,k]*A[k,j]` returns True or False.  Only one = needed.  Majid's answer shows a much better approach.

Comment: I made the changes, but the matrix which i am getting doesn`t match with the actual result.

Comment: In my assignment I am not allowed to use the direct method , i am supposed to do it by loops

Comment: @MedhaShringari I have added your fixed code as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is the recommended solution:

```
A.dot(A.transpose())
```

Also, below is the fixed version of your code:

```
import numpy as np


def multiply_At_A(A):
    dim1, dim2 = A.shape
    matrix = np.zeros([dim2, dim2])

    for i in range(dim1):
        for j in range(dim2):
            for k in range(dim2):
                matrix[i, j] += A[i, k] * A[j, k]
    return matrix


A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
print(multiply_At_A(A))
```